# Codeigniter gives 404 error on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an upload form which after ajax upload 2 buttons allow the user to change the uploaded photo or delete it. I've implemented the whole system right and works fine. but my problem is and was when I tried to make an ajax call to the function that deletes photos it gave me `csrf protection error`. after I disabled `csrf protection` , now it says `404 not found` in my response.

**PHP:**//url: "http://localhost/project/index.php/ajax/deleteCarPhoto/"

```
function deleteCarPhoto()
{
    $src = $this->input->post('src');

    $adPhotos = $this->session->userdata('ad_photos');
    unset($adPhotos[$src]);

    $this->session->set_userdata('ad_photos',$adPhotos);

    echo "<p>Photo deleted</p>";
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("label.btn-danger").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedElement = this;
    var name = $(this).parents("label").find("input[type=file]").attr('name');
    var src = $(this).parents("label").find("img").attr("src");
    var pattern = /\/([A-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg))/ig;
    var result = pattern.exec(src)[1];

    $.post({
            url: "http://localhost/project/index.php/ajax/deleteCarPhoto/",
            data: {src : result},
            dataType:'html'
    },function(xhr){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"none");
        $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/assets/images/upload_a_photo.png') no-repeat center center");
        $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('input[type=file]').removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#upload").reset();
    });
});
```

**My HTTP HEADERS:**

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Cookie  ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; un4vW7pAFT=aNdO76M9erJW9lpHvJtS9SILUiZqb%2FgYGb5Zr9liqlVP3hzLupNYgeWlRAeGOME6mK4xE7ATNdmr%2FVSLdkFsyMX4foVtEzmxOsT%2BX9N9K%2FdqDMTaL0pYlvxloe5zYHYBXHanmSbMhWhPvcZO65HGb29VZsnquPuR%2BVwAnyFsd3R7l0s7TjutaydBdcgUvRUv1n1FkqRZ5oTQ2JfW8RGo7Pye4Lb4VA8OLyzVTgmroVkr%2FA3g24y82EWHAPyv%2B4riDiYmmxVKDWmWdMZ7Ms4sqibYVw4woUyXtNxoWvD6vSphcpw9oPCIsm2guCyf3hJlaIuVvdM0sRvxPf3tz0zvIA%3D%3D
Host    localhost
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://localhost/project/index.php/advertise/add
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: `404 - site not found` is a web server (apache, nginx etc.) error code. If this is the code you get, then most probably CodeIgniter was never even invoked (unless CI redirect to a bad page, or threw a 404 header). Btw, are you inventing new protocols here (`h t t p` != `http`)?

Comment: @RainFromHeaven,when I enter the url in a browser it works but not in ajax, and also Its the Stackoverflow Url Validation While Asking Protocol. ;)

Comment: `h t t p://localhost/project/index.php/ajax/deleteCarPhoto/` This link should, **IN NO WAY**, work when entered as URL. In FireFox 24 it redirects me to the search results for that link as a keyword. HTTP is a protocol, H T T P is just text.

Comment: need to send `csrf_token_name` with ajax if csrf protection enabled. Can get value from form if using form helper, or from cookie

Answer (score 2):

If I am a browser, then localhost if my computer. If I am browsing your site http://www.your-web-domain/some/url, then an ajax link to localhost will still refer to my workstation. The link in the script should be http://www.your-web-domain//project/index.php/ajax/deleteCarPhoto/

Comment: So how I might test ajax in localhost while my domain is not ready?